# What web server to use for Lua web development

Tags: apache, lua, webserver, nginx, lighttpd

What web server (and why) should I use for Lua web development?

Answer (score 39):

There are a few Lua-based webservers around:

- [Xavante](http://www.keplerproject.org/xavante/) seems to be the most popular.
- [Haserl](http://haserl.sourceforge.net/) is nice and small.
- [Nanoki](http://alt.textdrive.com/nanoki/) is not strictly a webserver, but a nice small pure Lua wiki engine worth studying. As for the Lua wikies, there is also [Sputnik](http://sputnik.freewisdom.org/), which is fully featured and very flexible, but is a bit on the slow side.
- There is [mod_lua](http://oss.digirati.com.br/mod%5Flua/2.0/) (ex mod_wombat) if you prefer Apache. Looks like it [would make it](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2008-12/msg00119.html) into the next Apache distribution as a core module.
- Note that it is not so hard to write [a FastCGI Lua module](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/lua).
- There is also [Luv](http://in.aisys.ru/Luv) Lua MVC web-framework project ([GitHub page](http://github.com/temiy/luv)). It is not mature yet, but may contain some interesting insights.

Update. Some more frameworks to check out:

- Luvit: http://luvit.io/ (too node-like for my taste)
- ngx_lua module for nginx: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule
- TIR for mongrel2: http://tir.mongrel2.org/
- Ophal: http://ophal.org (web platform)
- lev: https://github.com/connectFree/lev
- Turbo: https://github.com/kernelsauce/turbo

Comment: This answer is outdated, there is: openresty, lapis, tir.mongrel and luvit to mention some.

Answer (score 27):

We've been working on the ngx_lua module for nginx, which supports 100% non-blocking network traffic to mysql, PostgreSQL, memcached, other http services, and more, hence outstanding concurrency level and over-all performance :)

http://github.com/chaoslawful/lua-nginx-module

and we're using it in production :)

Comment: Sold! I'd much rather get deep into Lua vs Javascript/Node.

Answer (score 7):

The best web server I can think for lua web development is [mongrel2](http://mongrel2.org). Take a look on [TIR framework](http://tir.mongrel2.org), which, [IMHO](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/IMHO), is the best lua use for web development these days.

Answer (score 5):

For development, it can be handy to run a small test server. A good candidate in particular for Lua web development is the [Xavante](http://www.keplerproject.org/xavante/) server which is part of the Kepler project. Aside from some of the supporting Kepler modules , Xavante itself is written in pure Lua.

For production, the new `mod_lua` (which had been known as `mod_wombat` before the Apache team accepted it into the core set of modules) running on Apache would seem to be a well-respected choice.

Answer (score 2):

there is as well the LuCI project [1]. which is the LuaConfigurationInterface, the web based mangement frontend for OpenWRT (embedded Linux).

The LuCI guys wrote also a very small webserver, called lucittpd. 
LuCI is an MVC as well.
And in production state ;)

[1] http://luci.subsignal.org

Answer (score 0):

Recently, Lua support was added to the http://github.com/valenok/mongoose web server, check out pre-build windows binary at http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/downloads/list