# webframeworks in lua?

Tags: lua, web-frameworks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What web server to use for Lua web development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166684/what-web-server-to-use-for-lua-web-development)

Are there any good web frameworks in Lua?

Comment: "Web framework" is not the same as "web server"

Comment: No need to reopen this just to vote close as not constructive

Comment: this admins closing questions drives me nuts, please reopen, as @bstpierre said: web framework != web server, for god sake!

Comment: http://leafo.net/lapis/ <---- this framework looks promising

Comment: Answers are really wrong! take a look at http://lua-users.org/wiki/LibrariesAndBindings for up-to-date info.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.keplerproject.org/